# Spring Boot Thymeleaf Method POST SELECT null

Tags: spring-boot, select, thymeleaf

Guys.
Tell me please how to get values from select in the Controller?
This returns null.
request.getParameter("firstUserYears");
request.getParameter("secondUserYears");

I want to get value of "birthDay" field.

my thymeleaf html form:

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Insert title here</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    
    <form method="post" action="/calculate_years">
    <select name="firstUserYears" th:field="*{users}"/>
    <option th:each="user : ${users}" th:value="firstUserYears" th:text="${user.firstName}">
    </option>
    </select>

    <select name="secondUserYears" th:field="*{users}"/>
    <option th:each="user : ${users}" th:value="${user.firstName}" th:text="${user.firstName}">
    </option>
    </select>
    
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
                        
    </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Controller:

```
    @GetMapping("/user-difference")
    public String calculateDifferenceForm(Model model) {
         model.addAttribute("users", service.findAll());    
         return "user-difference";
    }
    
    
    @PostMapping("/calculate_years")
    public String calculateDifferenceForm(HttpServletRequest request, @ModelAttribute User user,
            BindingResult bindingResult){
    
            String firstUsersYearsOld = request.getParameter("firstUserYears");
            String secondUsersYearsOld = request.getParameter("secondUserYears");
            String name = request.getParameter("name");
            
            BindingResult results = bindingResult;
            
            System.out.println(results);
            System.out.println(user);
            System.out.println(name);
            System.out.println(firstUsersYearsOld);
            System.out.println(secondUsersYearsOld);
            
        return "redirect:/user-difference";
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should start with defining a form data object. For example:

```
public class AgeDifferenceFormData {
  private long user1Id;
  private long user2Id;

  // getters and setters here
}
```

Create an empty such object in your `@GetMapping`:

```
    @GetMapping("/user-difference")
    public String calculateDifferenceForm(Model model) {
         model.addAttribute("formData", new AgeDifferenceFormData());
         model.addAttribute("users", service.findAll());    
         return "user-difference";
    }
```

Now update your HTML form to use the form data object:

```
<form method="post" action="/calculate_years" th:object="${formData}">
    <select th:field="*{user1Id}"/>
        <option th:each="user : ${users}" th:value="${user.id}" th:text="${user.firstName}">
        </option>
    </select>

    <select th:field="*{user2Id}"/>
        <option th:each="user : ${users}" th:value="${user.id}" th:text="${user.firstName}">
        </option>
    </select>
    
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
                        
    </form>
```

Note how you need to:

- Set a selected object for Thymeleaf via `th:object="${formData}"`
- Set the dedicated field for each select via `th:field="*{user1Id}"` and `th:field="*{user2Id}"`
- Use the unique id of the user for the `th:value`.

Now in your `@PostMapping` method do this:

```
@PostMapping("/calculate_years")
    public String calculateDifferenceForm(@ModelAttribute("formData") AgeDifferenceFormData formData,
            BindingResult bindingResult){
    
            User user1 = service.getUser(formData.getUser1Id());
            User user2 = service.getUser(formData.getUser2Id());
            // calculate age difference here
            
        return "redirect:/user-difference";
    }
```

See also [Using HTML select options with Thymeleaf](https://www.wimdeblauwe.com/blog/2021/04/16/using-html-select-options-with-thymeleaf/) for more info.

Comment: You are welcome, please use the checkmark next to the answer to accept it so other know the question has been answered.